# std::filesystem::exists -- Do I need to check the std::error_code value if the function returns true?

Tags: c++, c++17, error-code

[std::filesystem::exists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/exists) is used to check "if the given file status or path corresponds to an existing file or directory." In my code, I am using the definition with the following signature:

```cpp
bool exists( const std::filesystem::path& p, std::error_code& ec ) noexcept;
```

My question is: if the function returns the boolean value `true`, do I still need to check the value of the error code `ec`? Or can I assume that, if `std::filesystem::exists` returns `true`, then there is no error and `(bool)ec` is `false`?

For example, suppose I have the following:

```cpp
std::error_code ec;
std::filesystem::path fpath = "fname";
bool does_exist = std::filesystem::exists(fpath, ec);
if (does_exist) {
    ...
}
```

Is it necessary to check that `(bool)ec == false` within the `if (does_exist) { ... }` block?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`std::filesystem`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/exists) library evolved out directly from the corresponding [Boost library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm). As several functions in the Boost libraries (such as Boost ASIO) it offers [two interfaces](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/application_development/9781782163268/1/ch01lvl1sec10/exceptions-versus-error-codes) that use a different type of error handling

```
bool exists(std::filesystem::path const& p);
bool exists(std::filesystem::path const& p, std::error_code& ec) noexcept;
```

The first version uses *exceptions* (that have to be caught with a `try... catch` construct) while the second one does not but instead one has to evaluate the error codes. This **error code** might then contain **additional information about the precise reason of the failure** and help with debugging if the function returns `false`.

> The overload that does not take a std::error_code& parameter throws
> filesystem_error on underlying OS API errors, constructed with p as
> the first path argument and the OS error code as the error code
> argument. The overload taking a std::error_code& parameter sets it to
> the OS API error code if an OS API call fails, and executes ec.clear()
> if no errors occur. Any overload not marked noexcept may throw
> std::bad_alloc if memory allocation fails.

If the function returns **`true`** on the other hand it is **safe to assume that the path exists**.

Error codes are more lightweight and in particular convenient for real-time performant code, numerical simulations and high-performance applications. In these cases one might turn off exception handling entirely for the compilation process just to have better performance. On the other hand error codes are often harder to maintain as for nested code - if a routine fails in some subfunction - you will have to pass the error code through several layers to where the error should be handled. Exceptions in this regard are easier maintainable.

Answer (score 3):

From cppreference:

> The overload taking a `std::error_code&` parameter sets it to the OS API error code if an OS API call fails, and executes `ec.clear()` if no errors occur.

No, you don't *need* to. It's better to only use it if the call fails. Any other time `ec` will not have any useful information in it.

You can enforce this using `if-initializer` statements so the error code is only declared inside the smallest scope possible:

```cpp
std::filesystem::path fpath{"fname"};
if(std::error_code ec{}; !std::filesystem::exists(fpath, ec)) {
    std::cerr << "File system returned the following for \"" << fpath.string() << "\":\nError: " << ec.value() << "\nMessage: " << ec.message();
}
```